# arcpy codes to write ranked values

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

I have a dataset with ranked attributes(e.g. very low, low, moderate, high, very high). I would like to write a python code using arcpy to give a numeric values to each rank, such as 0,5,10,20,50,100. I created a new field to save these values, and I am now struggling to write a simple code that translate each rank to a numeric value.
any ideas ?

Answer (score 4):

Since you've already created your field to store the integer ranks you can use the **Field Calculator** with the following codeblock (this code assumes your string, or text, ranks are stored in the field *rank* and your new field for storing the integer ranks is *num_rank*):

[image: Field Calculator window for *num_rank* field]

For each feature in your dataset, the corresponding *rank* value (very low, low, moderate, high, very high) is pushed into the calc_num_rank function. In that function the text form of the rank is mapped to a numeric value; it is this numeric value that is returned as your *num_rank* value.

Your dataset's attributes should then look similar to this:

[image: Result]

**Note:**
The code inside the codeblock makes use of a dictionary to store the string and corresponding numeric rank values. You can expand/edit this dictionary to match your dataset's attributes and desired numeric rankings. If you are unfamiliar with dictionaries in python check out [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 2):

This is another way

```
rank_dictionary = {'very low':0, 'low':5, 'moderate':20,'high':50, 'very high':100}
shapefile = 'dataset'
fields = ['Rank_txt', 'Rank_num']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shapefile, fields) as Cursor:
     for row in Cursor:
         row[1] = rank_dictionary.get(row[0])
         Cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started. My assumption is that RANK is your attribute string field and RANK_NUM is your rank numerical value field.

```
attributes = [['very low',0], ['low',5], ['moderate',20], ['high',50], ['very high',100]]
dataset_lyr = "dataset_lyr"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("dataset.shp", dataset_lyr)
for att in attributes:
    selection = '"' + "RANK = '" + att[0] + "'" +'"'
    selection_type = "NEW_SELECTION"
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (dataset_lyr, selection_type,selection)
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(dataset_lyr, "RANK_NUM", att[1], "PYTHON_9.3","")
```